# Convert ordinal string to numeric in sas enterprise miner

Tags: variables, encoding, sas

I have a dataset that looks like this

| Gender | Size | Color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Male | small | Red |
| Female | Large | Blue |
| Female | Large | Blue |
| Female | Medium | Black |
| Male | Small | Blue |

And I want to change it to look this way in sas enterprise miner

| Gender | Size | Color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |

Please how do I go about it

Comment: What did you try? Is the case of the values really inconsistent? `small` and `Small` are two different strings.  Check the definition of the original variable. Is it really a character string? Or is it a numeric variable with a format attached that is making the numeric values display as Medium, Large, etc.

Comment: I do not  really know how to go about it. The case of the values are consistent. The values are string.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.